# SFUserAccountManager loses its details in once app is terminated

Tags: community, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, ipad

I have an iPad app with `Salesforcemobilesdk-ios` integrated. First time, as soon as I login I set all the credentials in oauthCoordinatorDidAuthenticate method like this -

```
- (void) oauthCoordinatorDidAuthenticate: (SFOAuthCoordinator *) coordinator authInfo:(SFOAuthInfo *)info 
{

    [SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].coordinator = coordinator;
    [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] coordinator].credentials = coordinator.credentials;
    SFUserAccount *userAccount = [[SFUserAccount alloc]initWithIdentifier:s_currentAccountIdentifier];
    userAccount.credentials = coordinator.credentials;
    userAccount.accessScopes = coordinator.scopes;
    [SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].currentUser = userAccount;
    [[SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance] applyCredentials:coordinator.credentials];
    [[SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance] saveAccounts:nil];
}
```

It works fine when I try and check valid `OAuth` session when I am using or in background.

But when I close the app(app terminated) and launch it again, `SFUserAccountManager` couldn't retrieve the details and check for valid session, instead showing salesforce login screen again.

How to make sure that `SFUserAccountManager` and `SFAuthenticationManager` saves its details even when I close the app and launch it again.

Thanks!